# jQuery: sor(t)table not working on new versions of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I would like to use this jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/NyQPD/59/ with latest jQuery and jQuery UI library but its not working properly.

If you try to switch for newer versions, main functionality (**reordering table columns** by drag and drop) stops working right. Main difference is that of course in this fiddle is used sortTable and new versions support only sortable (with single T).

So my question is: is there a way to modify this fiddle to work the same way even if jQuery library is switched to 2.0.2?

I tried to modify it by adding this functionality (which obviously doesnt work properly):

```
 $('table').sortable({
     placeholder: 'placeholder',
     helperCells: 'td'
 }).disableSelection();
```

Or in a better way: can even jQuery UIs sortable function make table this sortable? (reordering its columns)

Comment: 2.0.X had major breaking changes. It would need to be upgraded

Comment: "isOverAxis" method removed from jquery UI 1.10.x. Then unfortunately jquery Migrate is not enough to fix issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/NyQPD/61/

Working fine at my end. After upgrading `jQuery` version also upgrade the `jQuery UI` version.

```
$(function () {
    $('#ex7').sorttable({
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        helperCells: 'td'
    })
});
```